# Can I use mod_cband and mod_vhost_alias together?

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, mod-cband

Basically I run a VPS and host my clients' sites on it. I have mod_vhost_alias set up to use the domain as the client's user account home folder, eg /home/www.example.com.
I'd like to use mod_cband to limit the bandwidth per domain too. I know I can do this per virtualhost, but I have it set up using mod_vhost_alias. Is this possible?

For your reference, this is what I have so far...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Doesn't matter as long as it's fake rlly
    ServerName bogusname
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%0/www

    # Bandwidth stuff
    CBandDefaultExceededURL http://clients.bradreed.co.uk/bandwidth_exceeded.html
    CBandLimit 100G
    # The following doesn't work
    CBandScoreboard /var/www/scoreboard/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO. As you have discovered the `%0` expansion is specific to the   [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) directives and not supported in other modules.

The main problem is that Apache's design is based on a static configuration, where mod_vhost_alias is simply put an exception, a hack. That makes it dynamic configuration of other modules and directive difficult.

If you want to use mod_cband, AFAIK you must start working with client specific virtual host entries and restart your webserver whenever a new client is on-boarded.

I imagine most providers with a mod_vhost_alias setup would parse the apache log files and use the resulting statistics as a bandwidth accounting tool.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will go to a manual configuration :)